# Changing folder structure in cypress cucumber

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I write some test cases using cypress and cucumber, and the test cases are running successfully if the folder structure is like this:

```
/integration
    /login
        login.js
    /registration
        registration.js
    login.feature
    registration.feature
```

But I want to keep all the feature files in one folder and the js files in another folder like this:

```
/integration
    /featureFiles
        login.feature
        registration.feature
    /testFiles
        login.js
        registration.js
```

If I make the folder structure like this, I got error. No test case runs.
Is it possible to make the structure like this? Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.5.4",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.20.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  }
}
```

and cypress.json file:

```
{
    "testFiles": "**/*.feature"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create common file using following folder structure, steps included here will be accessible in all the feature files

cypress\integration\common\common-step.ts

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these lines in `package.json` in cypress-cucumber-preprocessor section

`"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false, "stepDefinitions":"cypress/integration/featureFiles"`

[image]

Comment: Post text, not pictures of text.  You're forcing people to unnecessarily have to transcribe your solution by hand.

Comment: The "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false was the solution for me. If this is set to true, it seems that it requires the .feature files and the test to be in the same folder (with test files which can be is subfolders)